# Is there any way to merge two (or multiple) for loops to reduce the overall time complexity?

Tags: c++, algorithm, for-loop, data-structures, time

Actually I have solved the problem of comparing results of a calculation and returning the minimum value. Although the I successfully implemented the logic and executed the code finely but failed to reduce the time complexity.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

int checkMinimum(int array[], int index)
{
  int result = INT_MAX;

  for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    for(int j = 0; j < index; ++j)
      if(i != j && (min(result, ((array[i] & array[j]) ^ (array[i] | array[j]))) < result))
        result = min(result, ((array[i] & array[j]) ^ (array[i] | array[j])));

  return result;
}

void getMinimum()
{
  int index;
  cin >> index;
  int array[index];

  for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    cin >> array[i];

  cout << checkMinimum(array, index) << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int limit;
  cin >> limit;
  while(limit--)
    getMinimum();

  return 0;
}
```

After researching on for loops and trying to merge them together can't help at all because it's hard to fulfil the conditions of the loops into one.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
#include<climits>

using namespace std;

int checkMinimum(int array[], int index)
{
  int result = INT_MAX;

  for(int i = 0, j = index - 1; i != j; ++i, --j)
    if((min(result, ((array[i] & array[j]) ^ (array[i] | array[j]))) < result))
      result = min(result, ((array[i] & array[j]) ^ (array[i] | array[j])));

  return result;
}

void getMinimum()
{
  int index;
  cin >> index;
  int array[index];

  for(int i = 0; i < index; ++i)
    cin >> array[i];

  cout << checkMinimum(array, index) << endl;
}

int main()
{
  int limit;
  cin >> limit;
  while(limit--)
    getMinimum();

  return 0;
}
```

So how can I reduce the time complexity of this?

Comment: If you need to do an operation for every `(i,j)` pair, then you need to do `index^2` operations. No method of expressing this will change that fact. (If the problem you're trying to solve has a different solution, that's another question entirely.)

Comment: Time complexity may also be independent of the time the actual code generated by the compiler takes to execute on a particular hardware platform. You won’t win against quadratic (or worse) complexity on large datasets, but small datasets may well perform close to hardware limits even if they are quadratic, and that performance sometimes mat dwarf what a less complex algorithm would do if somehow it resulted in worse code. Algorithmic complexity these days requires a look at cache locality - without it you’re wasting your time.

Comment: The biggest problem I see in this code at low level is the forwarding penalty – the constant use of the result variable in the look is killing the performance. Another problem I see is that this looks like an N*log(N) algorithm to me, but is implemented in the most naive way that turns it into N^2. Hint: minimum implies sorting would help, and for that you can represent the data in a way that accounts for the binary operations so you won’t have to do them N times for every element.

Comment: Steps I’d take to improve it: figure out what sort of comparison operation could be used to sort the array (perhaps in more than one way on each array copy) so that some operation performed just once on the first elements of those arrays will yield the minimum you want. If this question is from a competitive programming site then I’m sure you need an NlogN solution as everything else would be trivial.

Comment: Are all numbers positive or is negative values a thing?

Comment: A simple web search would've also helped you: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/minimum-xor-of-or-and-and-of-any-pair-in-the-array/

Comment: @AbhinavMathur my problem isn't with the calculation but with the for loop. The problem is wanting the minimum calculated value and although it's possible to reduce the calculation logic but I am searching for a better methon to combine both the loops in one. The first code is taking more time for bigger dataset.

Comment: "reduce the calculation logic but I am searching for a better methon to combine both the loops in one". Isn't that the same thing?

Answer (score 3):

`(array[i] & array[j]) ^ (array[i] | array[j])` is equivalent to `array[i] ^ array[j]` (`&`, `^`, `|` are all bitwise operations; write the truth table for one bit).

To minimize the XOR, the most important thing is that the high-order bits agree. Let's say the input has several numbers `0xxxx` and several numbers `1xxxx`. There is no point in trying the pairs with a `0xxxx` and a `1xxxx`; even if the `xxxx` part is exactly the same, the XOR is `10000`, whereas the XOR of any `0xxxx` with any `0xxxx`, or the XOR of any `1xxxx` with any `1xxxx` is at most `01111`, which is less than `10000`.

Repeating this logic within each group at the next bit, and the one after that, it's possible to show that the pair with the minimum XOR appear next to each other in sorted order. Therefore you can sort the array and compute the minimum over `n − 1` adjacent pairs.